# Service IKEEXT automatically switched off after Windows 10 reboot

Tags: service, windows-10-desktop

After rebooting Windows 10, the IKEEXT service appears turned off - regardless of it previous state - started, stopped, automatically started or manually started.
No problem to disable or enable it or run manually. Why the state of IKEEXT can appear switched off?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some methods that you can try to trouble shoot the problem:

1.Make sure that the dependence of the this service is set to automatically start.

2.perform a clean boot to disable the 3-party software conflict.

3.Make sure the service is enabled in msconfig.
4.modify the service to automatic restart on failure.
4.change the startup type of these services from Automatic to Automatic Delayed.
-You can go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\IKEEXT\DelayedAutostart`
-Add `DelayedAutostart` entry but set value to 0,If nothing helps, you can check the Event Log to see if there is any related errors generated.